# How to Clone an element and replace and existing element with the cloned one?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, prototypejs

I am trying to populate a select box with around 5000 options getting from ajax call. I want to use the same data to update other 8 select boxes. I am using prototype.js and using the .update() function.
But the thing is it freezes the IE and Chrome for a while.
So, I am trying to create the first select box with the .update() function and then clone the select box and replace the other 8 select boxes with it.
Please suggest if that will increase the performance and how I can accomplish that.

Comment: If only this was tagged jQuery: `var clone = $('element').clone(); $('element').replaceWith(clone);`

Comment: Here's some sample code http://jsfiddle.net/marifrahman/hHgyX/2/

Comment: I have got a work around : http://jsfiddle.net/marifrahman/hHgyX/5/; But I am still not sure whether it actually improves the performance. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are pushing such a large number of options into the select boxes, the main javascript thread is doing all the work to populate the elements into the DOM (regardless of JS framework). In the future you will be able to spin off WebWorker threads to complete this work without blocking the main thread but until all browsers (ahem IE) support it I would not suggest implementing it.

I have 2 suggestions

1. Instead of populating the drop downs all at the same time make these [Ajax.Autocomplete](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter/) fields that query the results via ajax.
2. make the dropdowns show up in stages - after the first drop down is selected `clone()` it and then show the next one - the result is the same but the delays are broken up over time